# How to set style on a specific header in ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Im' trying to set style on a specific header in an ag-grid array generated dynamically. How Can I do this without manipulating the DOM ?
This is a timeslot array and I want to highlight the current day.

I already tried to apply cellStyle, but it can't affect headers. Do you have some ideas ?

Some code generating the array :

```
this.tmpDefs = [{ headerName: '', field: 'user', width: 90, suppressSizeToFit: true }];

for(wantedDays){
   this.tmpDefs.push([Some generated children])
}

this.gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.tmpDefs);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `headerClass` property in your column definition.

Here is the full documentation about column properties:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/

Comment: Thanks, I have now the class on the correct header, but how can I overried css property of ag-grid ?

Comment: The same way as you do with any CSS. Just use your css class to change the header's style

Comment: Very Good find. Thanks